# Google Chrome extension: How to find out if a user has signed in to the Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

As part of a Google Chrome extension that I'm building I need to be able to tell if a user has signed in to the Google Chrome browser while the extension is enabled.

How can I do this?

Please note that using OAuth2 (and thus, [the `chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity)) is beyond the scope of my project so I need to find another way.

EDIT: my question is not a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971491/detecting-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-from-a-chrome-extension) because the solution in that thread no longer works.

Comment: chrome.identity is the only api for that. Why do you need another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting whether user is logged in or not from a Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971491/detecting-whether-user-is-logged-in-or-not-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean signed into chrome, e.g. from the chrome://settings page, or just signed into a google account without signing into chrome itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if [`LSID` cookie](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/google_apis/gaia/gaia_auth_fetcher.cc?q=%5C%22LSID%5C%22&sq=package:chromium&l=356&dr=C) is set:

```
chrome.cookies.get({url:'https://accounts.google.com', name:'LSID'}, function(cookie) {
    if (cookie) {
        console.log('Sign-in cookie:', cookie);
    }
});
```

manifest.json permissions: `"cookies", "https://accounts.google.com/"`

Comment: I've just tested this where: 1.) The user is signed in to Gmail but not the Chrome browser; 2.) The user is signed in to both Gmail and the Chrome browser. It appears that the retrieved cookie in both cases is identical. Is there any cookie information that can tell me if a person isn't signed in to the Chrome browser even if they have signed in to Gmail?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Try poking the other cookies on that domain, maybe using a cookie editor extension.

Comment: seems this detects website sign-in, not chrome sign-in. Ive researched and seems the only possible way is with chrome.identity with email scope in the manifest. then if email is empty, user is not signed-in.

Answer (score 2):

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: false}, function (token) {
    if (!token) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError.message.match(/not signed in/)) {
            console.log("not singed in");
        } else {
            console.log("singed in");
        }
    }
});
```

And don't forget to add `"identity"` to permissions.

Comment: And how do you check after 3 days if you're still signed in?