# Are there any cookies that indicate if a user has signed in to the Google chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I know that the [LSID cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38989099/5508297) can be used to tell if a user has signed in to some Google account but unfortunately I can't rely on that cookie as an indicator  of being signed in to the Chrome browser because it also appears if someone is signed in to Gmail *while not being signed in to the Chrome browser.*

Are there any cookies (or other indicators) that show if someone is signed in to the Chrome browser?

**EDIT:** FYI: I've just looked at `chrome://settings/cookies` and there is no difference between the `chrome.google.com` cookies when signed in to Gmail and signed in to the Chrome browser vs. signed in to Gmail and not signed in to the Chrome browser. The same goes for the `accounts.google.com` cookies.

Comment: I am not used to write chrome extensions. but I will take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/signedInDevices#method-get

Comment: He is looking for the services that they are signed into, not which devices they are signed in from.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are. I am not an expert with Chrome Cookies, but I know that you can view them if you go to `chrome://settings/cookies` in your browser. Then search for chrome in the box. Here's an example of what one looks like, this one is title `_utmz`: [image: Check this out]

There is also a `_utma` cookie, so be sure to do some further looking into the `chrome://settings/cookies` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I've just edited my question - I'd appreciate it if you could take a look :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of to determine that would be by first checking if there is a cookie for chrome.google.com, then checking if one even exists for mail.google.com. If the one for mail is not there, then they must only be signed into only Chrome. Kind of a hack-ish answer, but I couldn't find a way through only the cookies

Comment: Yes, that could work for some use cases however, unfortunately, it doesn't for mine because my extension runs in Gmail so there will always be a cookie for mail.google.com

Comment: Damn...you could look for the specific cookie under mail.google.com that is related to only the user being logged in? I'm not sure how difficult that may be though. I will keep researching/looking into other ways over the next day or so. Sorry I couldn't help out more

Comment: I've just been searching via Chrome DevTools for specific cookies like that but unfortunately can't find anything yet. Let me know if you find anything - I'm very grateful for your help! :)